# Haskell - List comprehension, create/extend tuple list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make compact update rules for a list of tuples.

This is an example of an update rule:

```
rule1: [(a,b) | (a,b) <- zip [1..3] [2..4]]
λ:[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

What I want:

```
rule2: [(a,b) (b,a) | (a,b) <- zip [1..3] [2..4]]
λ(expected):[(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(3,4),(4,3)]
```

Is something like this possible in Haskell's list comprehension?

---

A possible solution that works, but I find it a bit ugly is:

```
concat [[(a,b),(b,a)] | (a,b) <- zip [1..3] [2..4]]
λ: [(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(3,4),(4,3)]
```

Comment: Is the order of the result important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First,** in your `rule1`, you don't need the list comprehension at all. The result of `zip` is already the list of tuples that you want:

```
rule1 = zip [1..3] [2..4]
```

**For** `rule2`, however, you can just use two nested generators, the second one derived from each element of the first, like this:

```
rule2 = [p | (a, b) <- zip [1..3] [2..4], p <- [(a, b), (b, a)]]
```

Or, alternatively, without destructuring the tuples, using [`swap`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.13/base-4.14.3.0/Data-Tuple.html#v:swap) instead:

```
rule2 = [p | p0 <- zip [1..3] [2..4], p <- [p0, swap p0]]
```